# How to write clean code in the "if" statement?

Tags: java, code-cleanup

What will be more clear and why? (using Apache Commons library)

In code below logic is the same:

```
if(!ArrayUtils.isEmpty(someArray)) {
  some code here ...
}

//or this variant
if(ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(someArray)) {
  some code here ...
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Ask this on CodeReview.

Comment: The second variant is cleaner. The clean code should not contain `!` or `!=`.

Comment: Yes for me it is also more clear using second variant, but according to java naming convention right name without NOT.
http://geosoft.no/development/javastyle.html#Specific

Comment: @zelinskyi about which rule are you talking exactly?

Comment: Rule 14. All method are without NOT.
You can find: isSet, isVisible, isFinished, isFound, isOpen

Answer (score 2):

1. The second one (using isNotEmpty) reads like plain English which is the main advantage of it.
2. if a library you're using provides exact functionality you need than you should use it (that is the case in your example).
3. In your particular case of ArrayUtils, checking if array is not empty or null is so common case that an API designer suggested to add a separate function for it.

Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand. 
- Martin Fowler

Comment: Continue:
Code will be read many more times than it's written. Write for readability.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for option #2. It's easier to read. It's clear that Commons has added this 
method exactly for not using option #1.

Answer (score 0):

I also think option 2 is better as it is more readable. I don't see any performance difference in these 2 options.

Comment: the question was not about performance but about cleanness i.e. readability ;)